# How to find the base part of a variable name that ends in I, J, or IJ

Tags: regex, r

I want to cut off the end part of a vector of characters of variable length that all end in either I, J, or IJ, but haven't quite got it right yet:

Current attempt, using a simple case.

```
vars <- c("VARI", "VARJ", "VARIJ")
sapply(vars, function(v) {
  m <- regexec("^(.*)(?:I|J|IJ)$", v)
  regmatches(v, m)[[1]][2]
})
```

However, it doesn't work for the IJ case:

```
 VARI   VARJ  VARIJ 
"VAR"  "VAR" "VARI"
```

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Try putting the `IJ` first in the group:</strike>

```
^(.*?)(?:IJ|J|I)$
```

It'll match `IJ` before trying to match `I` or `J` alone.

Then make the `.*` lazy (by adding a `?`) to prevent the `.` from eating too much.

EDIT: Actually, I messed up. Here's the deal:

In `^(.*)(?:J|I|IJ)$`, `.*` will match as much as possible, meaning the whole string. In the case of `VARIJ`, it will backtrack to `VARI` and see that the `(?:J|I|IJ)$`` part matches.

Making the `.*` lazy (by adding a `?`), the dot will first match `V` in `VARIJ`, then as there are no matches for ``` (?:J|I|IJ)$`` will continue with matching ```A`. When it reaches`R`, it finds a match in`(?:J|I|IJ)$`` and stops eating more characters.

I initially messed up since this question was a bit like a previous one where something like `(1|5|10|50|100|500)` was used to match `500` but only `5` got matched. This is different here because of the end of line anchor `$`. I apologize for not having noticed the variation immediately.

Conclusion, you can still use `(?:J|I|IJ)$` as long as `.*` is lazy.

Comment: Tested this and get the same output

Comment: @mindless.panda Oh, I forgot something; make the `.*` lazy as well. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 4):

What about good old simple `gsub` which is vectorised so you just need to do...

```
gsub( "I$|J$|IJ$" , "" , vars )
#[1] "VAR" "VAR" "VAR"
```

`$` anchors the regex at the end of the string and then matches either `I` or `J` or `IJ` and replaces them with nothing.